# return response()->json($data) me convierte decimal con 2 digitos a no redondeado

Tags: php, laravel, json

intento devolver de una consulta hecha a mi controlador Laravel en php, y en la respuesta me transforma el valor del monto, ya formateado a decimal con 2 digitos en un decimal con 16 digitos.

Controlador entrega:

```
$saldo_amv = 16800.09;            
$saldo = (float)number_format($saldo_amv, 2, '.', '');

return response()->json(['success' => 'TRUE', 'saldo' => $saldo, 'error' =>'']);
```

y del codigo del controlador, una vez consumido, entraga saldo con el numero sin redondear.

```
{
"success": "TRUE",
"saldo": 16800.0999999999985448084771633148193359375,
"error": ""
```

}

De que manera puedo hacer para que me erogue sin toda la chorrrera de dígitos, como se ve en el JSON sino que solo 2 digitos como se preformateo?

Comment: No uses `float` para valores monetarios. Usa [la clase ayudadora de Laravel  llamada `Number`](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-number-utility-class), que para eso existe. Y para PHP puro, [`NumberFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php), en la cual está basada `Number` de Laravel. Otro consejo, NO formatees al enviar, sino al consumir los datos. Por algo muy simple, ese dato puede recibirse en Alemania, o en Estados Unidos, y según el país, puede que necesites signos o formatos propios de ese país. Si formateas al enviar, capas el dato.

Comment: No tenemos el problema del formato de acuerdo al pais es todo dentro de el mismo pais, el inconveniente con el cual me encuentro es que al momento de entregar por return el response()->json() me convierte el valor de la variable $saldo de decimal con 2 digitos a decimal con unos 20 digitos . . . parece ser un problema de config de servidor web o algo extraño del php . . no lo se.

Comment: Me refiero a que en el `return` intentes ponerlo así: **`'saldo' => $saldo_amv`**

Comment: php < 7.4 tiene esos quirks con precision y json encode

Answer (score 0):

para quien le pueda servir encontré una respuesta a mi propio problema:

No se trataba de so convertia bien o mal el decimal con 2 digitos o no, de hecho las sugerencias recibidas son correctas y las abrazo en este caso.

Sucedía lo siguiente:

En mi `PHP.ini` faltó agregar la siguiente configuracion para que tome el formateo que ya le habia propinado a mi numero.

```
precision = 17
serialize_precision = -1
```

y solucioné mi inconveniente.

Agradezco la atención que obtuve y la ayuda.
Aquí queda para consultas si alguien le sirve .

Saludos

Comment: te conviene setear las settings via [`ini_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ini-set.php) cosa de no afectar otras partes de la app ( el valor se mantiene hasta q finaliza ese script )